# Formaldehyde in water-based stains

Tags: staining

I chose a water-based stain, Minwax Water-Based (https://www.minwax.com/wood-products/stains/minwax-water-based-wood-stain), for my recent unfinished pine shelving project mostly for the lower VOC content. However I was surprised to see formaldehyde on the SDS, especially when you don't often see that on the supposedly more toxic oil-based stuff.

For indoor air quality, does anyone know if this kind of formaldehyde concentration is a concern? Concentration is reported as <0.1% by weight, don't know if that's significant or not. I was hoping to avoid any sort of finish or sealer, not sure if that would help or not.

Comment: I presume you live in the US, if so this level of formaldehyde shouldn't concern you as your typical indoor environments have measurable levels of formaldehyde anyway due to the extensive use of sheet goods in construction in North America. And of course the product passes the health regs to begin with ;-)

Comment: @Graphus Sir (ma'am?), your knowledge appears boundless, and I respect that.  I would ask one wee favor: could you give your answers as answers, rather than as comments?  I can't tell you how many times I've looked through the list of "unanswered" questions, only to find that you've answered 95% of them, but in the comments section where the answers don't register as answers, let alone get accepted.  Thanks for the knowledge you've imparted, and thanks in advance for this little favor I'm asking!